# How do I Save request and response xml of soap java webservice that I host on Tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap

Currently this is how I create a soap webservice in eclipse.

1. I create a new Dynamic web project.
   [image]
2. Create a Class in my Example "MyWebservice" and also create a function that will be called when another system requires my websservice.

[image]

3. I then use the right mouse button Create webservice.

[image]

4. I then Export the project as a WAR file and deploy it in Tomcat.

[image]

My Question : Is is possible  in my webservice class to capture the Request and Response xml when my service is called from another system. I want to be able to store this request and response xml for investigation purposes.

If it is possible what should I do or can you please help me with an example.

The webservice WAR file is deployed on TOMCAT.

Comment: For debugging purposes you can use something like [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org). In Eclipse there is also a [TCP/IP-Monitor](https://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/monitoring-http-requests-and-responses-using-tcpip-monitor-in-eclipse). It works like a proxy. So the client calls the proxy which is able to log the in and outcoming messages and redirects them to the original server.

Comment: Thanks, Its not for debugging I want to store it for future investigations for example on the data that it was run on and not the current data for example if you run it now using soap ui it uses the current data but our data is always changing.

Comment: Also I would like to do some config in my java class to first check setup in my db to check for this service if I need to store the xml and in what folder.

Comment: It works well when we consume a webservice, but now we are hosting webservices and I would like the same functionality.